# HiDPI on external monitor (Dell u2515h) with Macbook Pro

Tags: display, resolution

So I have Dell U2515H connected to my Macbook Pro 15" Mid 2014 (integrated graphics) and when I try to run it in 16:9 1280x720 HiDPI (I'm using switchresx) resolution it has no effect. However, when I choose any other 16:10 HiDPI resolution like 1280x800 it works just fine but obviously it cuts the screen. Does anyone know what could be the problem? It is very weird that 16:10 resolutions are OK but 16:9 just don't work, given that native monitor aspect ratio is 16:9.

Comment: I have the same problem... any news?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the very same problem while setting HiDPI mode for my Macbook Pro with SwitchResX. As the HiDPI resolutions didn't fit, I made my own ones.

Here's how it goes:

- Follow the instructions on [SwitchResX's website](http://www.madrau.com/support/support/srx_1011.html) on how to temporarily disable "System Integrity Protection"
- On the SwitchResX panel for the DELL screen, go to the "Custom Resolutions" tab and create your desired resolutions under the "Scaled resolution" category.
- The pixels x lines you scale to are 2 times the "feeling" you want to get, e.g. 3840 x 2160 for a Full HD (1920 x 1080) feeling.

Disabling the SIP made the 720p resolution you mentioned work for me as well.

Comment: don't work with @Vajs question..., I have the same problem

Comment: @r1si , what exactly doesn't work? This is a solution to the exact same problem. Following these instructions you can create a custom resolution that matches the 16:9 scale, plus disabling SIP makes the bundled 16:9 ones work correctly

Comment: no... I disable sip , add custom resolution, but nothing see only 3840 x 2160 resolution without HiDPI choose here a video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78X4b-Bfpn8